# ASP.NET Core, AddScoped is not keeping data with same request

Tags: asp.net-core

Stuck in a project with AddScoped.

Then for testing, I created a new web application project in Asp.Net Core and created an interface and a class IMyInfo and MyInfo. It just has one integer property **mydata** and two methods **Increment() and GetData()**. The "Increment()" method just increase a value by 1 and "GetData()" method returns value of property "mydata". Through a TestingController, I am just executing the Increment() method and then call GetData().

When I am using AddSingleton service, it is giving an incremented value with every reload of request (i.e. 1,2,3,4 ...), but getting '1' every time when using AddScoped (not AddTransient).

Don't know where I am wrong?

***Below are all my codes:***

**I created the below interface and class in a new project:**

```
public interface IMyInfo
{
    void Increment();
    int GetData();
}

public class MyInfo : IMyInfo
{
    private int mydata = 0;

    public void Increment()
    {
        mydata++;
    }
    public int GetData()
    {
        return mydata;
    }

}
```

**Then created a TestController:**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMyInfo myInfo;

    public TestController(IMyInfo myInfo)
    {
        this.myInfo = myInfo;
    }

    public string Index()
    {
        myInfo.Increment();
        int d = myInfo.GetData();
        return d.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Here is my Startup file code:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddScoped<IMyInfo, MyInfo>();   // It is not giving me expected result...
        //services.AddSingleton<IMyInfo, MyInfo>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Test}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is an [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes) about service lifetimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's normal behavior.

When service is declared as *Scoped*, then it will has a new instance on every scope, by default ASP Core creates a new scope on every HTTP-Request, but you can create a Scope by your own (as @juunas correctly commented).

*Transient* will have a new instance every time that we will use it.

As @*Yiyi You* commented, [Service lifetimes docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes).

Comment: _Technically_ a scoped service is created per service scope, and ASP.NET Core creates a scope per request. And you can create scopes yourself too :)

Comment: I am new to asp.net core and just thinking it will work as a user's session data.
Thanks for your answer.